# How to create dynamic forms in flutter with FutureBuilder

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to create dynamic forms and fetch data after submitted form. I have an API and I'm getting questions from this API. In application, user will answer questions and save the result to API. How can I create dynamic forms and retrieve user inputs. Please help.

```
FutureBuilder<List<ConditionType>>(
        future: _api.getConditionTypes(job.sectorId),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
//Create Form
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [json_to_form](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/json_to_form), If you could share the structure of the response I could assist to tweaking the plugin which I had to do for my own project. I should mention that with this implementation DropDownButton tends to have issues displaying values though it saves them.

Answer (score 1):

I make the Json tranforms making the model of the object and then make the request:

```
class Model {
  String projectName;
  String datePlan;
  String activityName;
  String hours;

  TimeSheetModel({this.projectName, this.datePlan, this.activityName, this.hours});

  TimeSheetModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    projectName = json["ProjectName"];
    datePlan = json["DatePlan"];
    activityName = json["ActivityName"];
    hours = json["Hours"];
  }

  Map toMap() {
    var map = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    map["ProjectName"] = projectName;
    map["DatePlan"] = datePlan;
    map["ActivityName"] = activityName;
    map["Hours"] = hours;
    return map;
  }

}
```

The method fromJson transforms Json data to your object for GET request and toMap tranform your object to Json for POST or PUT request.

Making the GET request:

```
  getProjects() async {
    var url = 'url';
    var res = await http
        .get(Uri.encodeFull(url), headers: {"Accept": "application/json", 
        "charset": "UTF-8"});
    data = json.decode(res.body);
    setState(() {
      Model data = Model.fromJson(resBody);
    });
  }
```

Making the POST request:

```
  post() async {
    var url = 'url';
    http.post(url, body:
    data.toMap()).then((response) {
      print("Response status: ${response.statusCode}");
      print("Response body: ${response.body}");
    });
  }
```